# Busybox docker image dependancy chain

Tags: docker

I am new to Docker
I have run this

```
 sudo docker run --interactive --tty --link web:web --name web_test busybox:latest /bin/sh
```

I am trying to understand what does busybox actually represents.It seems it does not represent full Linux distribtuion.

Why and when do we need busybox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, busybox image is a small docker image that contains commonly available unix utilities. BusyBox is not a full linux distribution, it only contains the neccessary binaries needed to run common linux file and shell utils.

For more info, check https://hub.docker.com/_/busybox/